# how many connections will accept mysql node system

Tags: mysql

I have running one big web application and manipulate around 2 GP of data with 1500 users in a node system.i didn't go with server. while all users are in live the server goes down.
so want to know the below the things

1. How many connections MySQL(opensource) will accept at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to `/etc/my.cnf` file and check the maximum connection which is allowed.

The default setting for max_connections is 100. However you can update that.

You can change the setting to e.g. 200 by issuing the following command without having to restart the MySQL server

```
set global max_connections = 200;
```

Comment: First thanks for response.I know that already sir. my doubt was the capability of MySQL for maximum number of sessions in opensource.

Comment: @user3765017:- Then what you are looking for? I update my answer with the method of how you can update the maximum allowed connection!

Comment: @user3765017:- Also to add on CentOS, RedHat and similar distributions this is at `/etc/my.cnf;` other distros will store it elsewhere. I am not sure if I am able to answer you!

Comment: Can you provide us with server's CPU and RAM?

Comment: 8gp of ram and linux(ubundu) os.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a Too many connections error when you try to connect to the mysqld server, this means that all available connections are in use by other clients.

The number of connections permitted is controlled by the max_connections system variable. The default value is 151 to improve performance when MySQL is used with the Apache Web server. (Previously, the default was 100.) If you need to support more connections, you should set a larger value for this variable.

mysqld actually permits max_connections+1 clients to connect. The extra connection is reserved for use by accounts that have the SUPER privilege. By granting the SUPER privilege to administrators and not to normal users (who should not need it), an administrator can connect to the server and use SHOW PROCESSLIST to diagnose problems even if the maximum number of unprivileged clients are connected.

The maximum number of connections MySQL supports depends on the quality of the thread library on a given platform, the amount of RAM available, how much RAM is used for each connection, the workload from each connection, and the desired response time. Linux or Solaris should be able to support at least 500 to 1000 simultaneous connections routinely and as many as 10,000 connections if you have many gigabytes of RAM available and the workload from each is low or the response time target undemanding. Windows is limited to (open tables × 2 + open connections) < 2048 due to the Posix compatibility layer used on that platform.